# Twilio Question: Building subscription thru SMS

Tags: twilio, shortcode, sender

Im planning to build a console application. My plan is to build a subscription base thru sms. For example text SUBSCRIBE to 2600 then after application received sms the user will become subscriber. It will send news, announcement, events etc to user with senderID sms.

Is it possible in Twilio ? receiving sms in shortcode and notifying with sender id. Is it possible having 2 type of number in 1 account ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely use more than one type of number across an account, from local, national, short code and toll free numbers as well as using alphanumeric sender IDs in supported countries.